# Path problem involving diagonal movement

Tags: probability, probability-theory

You start off standing at what will be considered the origin and you can move either NE, NW, SE, or SW. For example your first move will take you to either (1,1), (-1, 1), (1,-1), or (-1,-1). How many ways are there to get to (a,b) in *n* steps? I know how to do something similar with the ballot problem but that only involves NE and SE movements so I'm not sure how to come up with an equation to get to (a,b) with these multiple movements involved. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Quick edit: In *n* steps was the original intention of the problem, not *after n* steps. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: This seems mispecified. I can move from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ and then back to $(0,0)$ as many times as I want.

Comment: How many ways to reach (a,b) after n steps was the problem though. If given infinite steps, then yeah you could reach, say, (0,0) in an infinite number of ways but if given a particular n like 4 for example then there would be a finite number of ways to reach (0,0), right?

Comment: Suppose you go from $(0, 0)$ and reach $(1, 1)$ in $n$ step, and $n$ has to be odd as the shortest path is a $1$-step NE. For the remaining $n-1$ steps, you fill up with NE-SW pair and NW-SE pair. say if you have $0$ NE-SW, then you have $(n-1)/2$ NW-SE. And you enumerate them from $\{0, (n-1)/2), (1, (n-3)/2), \ldots, ((n-1)/2, 0)\}$. Then use the multinomial coefficient to account for the possible permutations.

Comment: Just going to clarify, given we know the shortest path to the intended point, (say (1,1) in your example), you want to then sum up the possible NE-SW and NW-SE combinations you can achieve out of the remaining points (as going NE-SW or NW-SE gives you a net movement on your graph of basically 0). The number of ways to get to (1,1) in n steps would then be $\binom{n}{0,(n-1)/2}$ + $\binom{n}{1,(n-3)/2}$ + $\binom{n}{2,(n-5)/2}$ + ... + $\binom{n}{(n-1)/2,0}$. Would this then make our equation just a summation of binomial coefficients with the contents dependent on our target point?

Comment: I think I wrote that previous sum out wrong but I get the point, thanks for the help BGM

Answer (score 0):

At each step, your $x$ and $y$ coordinate both change by $\pm1$. We can count the number of walks by choosing which steps increase the $x$-coordinate, then independently choosing which steps increase the $y$ coordinate.

If the $x$ coordinate ends at $a$, there must be $\frac{n+a}2$ steps where $x$ increases and $\frac{n-a}2$ steps where $x$ decreases (which is only possible if $a$ has the same parity as $n$). There are therefore $\binom{n}{(n+a)/2}$ ways to choose how the $x$-coordinate chagnes. Similarly, the $y$-coordinates can be chosen in $\binom{n}{(n+b)/2}$ ways. Therefore, the number of ways to choose the walk is
$$
\binom{n}{(n+a)/2}\times \binom{n}{(n+b)/2}.
$$